# ASP.Net MVC datettime compare with nullable date time

Tags: asp.net-mvc

when my model property is declared with not null able date-time then no problem occur when we check data type of property but the moment i have a null able date time property then the below code return false

```
if (datatype.GetType().Equals(new DateTime().GetType()))
{}
```

### here is full code

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    ValidationResult validationResult = ValidationResult.Success;
    try
    {
        // Using reflection we can get a reference to the other date property, in this example the project start date
        var containerType = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
        var field = containerType.GetProperty(this.otherPropertyName);
        var extensionValue = field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
        var datatype = extensionValue.GetType();

        //var otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(this.otherPropertyName);
        if (field == null)
            return new ValidationResult(String.Format("Unknown property: {0}.", otherPropertyName));
        // Let's check that otherProperty is of type DateTime as we expect it to be
        if (datatype.GetType().Equals(new DateTime().GetType()))
        {
            DateTime toValidate = (DateTime)value;
            DateTime referenceProperty = (DateTime)field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            // if the end date is lower than the start date, than the validationResult will be set to false and return
            // a properly formatted error message
            if (toValidate.CompareTo(referenceProperty) < 1)
            {
                validationResult = new ValidationResult(ErrorMessageString);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            validationResult = new ValidationResult("An error occurred while validating the property. OtherProperty is not of type DateTime");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Do stuff, i.e. log the exception
        // Let it go through the upper levels, something bad happened
        throw ex;
    }

    return validationResult;
}
```

get me the idea of best fix because my property should be null able date time fields. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `field` (returned by call `GetProperty`) is type `PropertyInfo` so if you want the type withotu going to the value you need to call property `PropertyType`.

```
if (field.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || (field.PropertyType.IsGenericType && field.PropertyType == typeof(Nullable<DateTime>))) { }
```

Here is the [reference for PropertyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

You should convert your type checks to `typeof(TypeHere)` instead of `new TypeHere.GetType()`. The former does not have to create a new instance which could be expensive if the code is repeated / looped many times. See my example.

Also take @David's (the other answer) advice about using `throw;` instead of `throw ex;`. The later will reset the entire captured exception call stack.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear why you're comparing the *types* and not the *values*, but I guess that's beside the point.  In this comparison:

```
datatype.GetType().Equals(new DateTime().GetType())
```

This is going to return `true` if `datatype` is of type `DateTime`.  So, reasonably, it will *not* return true if `datatype` is of some other type, such as `Nullable<DateTime>`.

You should be able to compare with that type instead:

```
datatype.GetType().Equals(new Nullable<DateTime>().GetType())
```

Or perhaps with both:

```
datatype.GetType().Equals(new DateTime().GetType()) ||
datatype.GetType().Equals(new Nullable<DateTime>().GetType())
```

---

Side note:  Your `catch` block is entirely superfluous and is actually *removing* information about the exception.  It's something of an anti-pattern and should be removed entirely.  If you are *actually* handling the exception in any way in that `catch` block and *do* want to re-throw, just use `throw;` instead of `throw ex;`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check the type of a null value therefore you need to check if it's null before you do anything else.

```
if(datatype == null)
            validationResult = new ValidationResult(ErrorMessageString);        
else if (datatype.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
{
    if(!IsValidDate(datatype.Value))
            validationResult = new ValidationResult(ErrorMessageString); 
    ...
}
```